# Form Select - option which though selected will return the javascript valueMissing form API

Tags: javascript, html, forms

If I have a select like this (more to it than this but to keep it simple):

```
<select required>
<option value="000">---</option>
<option value="success">Success</option>
<option value="article">Article</option>
</select>
```

if I checkValidity() it will be true.

But I want 000 to count as "not filled out"

```
if(element.value === "000") {
   setErr(XXX);
}
```

So how do I get the standard browsers response to valueMissing?

I of course can just type the response in XXX but instead I would like to get the browsers localization.

I might be going at this backward, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's no "_standard browsers response_" for this situation, technically the first option is seleceted. Or I've totally misunderstood your question?

Comment: Why set a value at all if you want it to count as unselected?

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate the frame challenges, but this isn't a frame challenge: "The validationMessage read-only property of the HTMLObjectElement interface returns a string representing a localized message that describes the validation constraints that the control does not satisfy (if any). This is the empty string if the control is not a candidate for constraint validation (willValidate is false), or it satisfies its constraints."
How do I force that to occur is my question if the answer is "don't know" or "can't" totally understood.